# scp stopped working with bash: scp: command not found / lost connection

Tags: scp

I was always copying files with scp with

```
scp from to
```

Suddenly it stopped working with

```
#scp from host:/home/username/to
bash: scp: command not found
lost connection
```

or

```
#scp host:/home/username/to/file .
bash: scp: command not found
```

Why? What does it mean? And how to fix?

I can do

```
ssh host
```

successfully.

---

`scp` is here

```
#scp
usage: scp [-346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

Comment: Have you removed scp or modified PATH?

Comment: `scp` works by running `scp` on the server. Compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1634882/432690). In your case `lost connection` means the local `scp` probably works fine (if it didn't, there would be no connection in the first place). `bash: scp: command not found` comes from the remote side. Are you trying to connect to a server that used to support `scp`? Has your `PATH` changed on the server? Or has `scp` executable been removed from the server?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski isn't ability to ssh to the server sufficient?

Comment: Have you read the linked answer? At least the beginning of it? Your local `scp` runs `ssh … 'scp …'`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I read but I can't beleive my eyes. I was always assuming `scp` is a tool, which uses `ssh` to connect to the target and automates copying files with it. Even if it is not, I can't beleive, how it was working on my case but then stopped. Target machine has no `scp`, this is true.

Comment: Believe it. `scp` is a quick and dirty hack that stuck. That's why you need to quote some filenames twice: for the local and the remote shell. And you can inject code. E.g. this `scp 'router:nonexistent; beep' whatever` makes my router beep. You can only inject code you can run via `ssh` anyway, but if running code is not your intention and you don't know how to quote for `scp` then you may run something you don't want.